# Working with multiple checkbox

Tags: php, html

I m new to php.Please help me out with this!!!
I have an Student Application form in html and php.. with textbox and checkboxes. I am not able to read the value of the checkbox. Please help whats wrong with my code. Here is my html code and php code as well

index.php

```
    <div class="formWrapper">

    <div class="formLeft">
        <h4>Admission to LKG</h4>

        <form name="LKGForm" id="LKGForm" method="POST" action="pdf/pdf.php">

        <div class="formItem">
            <label>Student Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="LKGStudentName" id="LKGStudentName" />
        </div>

        <div class="formItem">
            <label>Student Date of Birth</label>
            <input type="text" name="LKGStudentDOB" id="LKGStudentDOB" />
            Ex: 01-Jan-2014
        </div>

        <div class="formItem">
            <label>Father Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="LKGParentName" id="LKGParentName" />
        </div>

        <div class="formItem">
            <label>Mother Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="LKGMotherName" id="LKGMotherName" />
        </div>

        <div class="formItem">
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="LKGEmail" id="LKGEmail" />
        </div>

        <div class="formItem">
            <label>Mobile Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="LKGContactNumber" id="LKGContactNumber" />
        </div>

        <div class="formItem">
            <label>Residential Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="LKGAddress" id="LKGAddress" />
        </div>

        <div class="formItem">
            <label>City</label>
            <input type="text" name="LKGCity" id="LKGCity" value="Bangalore" />
        </div>

        <div class="formItem">
            <label>Pin Code</label>
            <input type="text" name="LKGPincode" id="LKGPincode" />
        </div>
            <label>Parent is an Alumnus (old Boy) of this school </label> &nbsp&nbsp
        <input type="checkbox" name="LKGAlumnus" value="Yes" id="LKGAlmnus" >Yes &nbsp&nbsp
            <input type="checkbox" name="LKGAlumnus" value="No" id="LKGAlmnus" >No &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp

        <div class="formItem">
            <input type="hidden" name="formType" id="formType" value="LKG" />
            <input type="button" name="LKGSubmit" id="LKGSubmit" value="Submit" class="formButton" />
        </div>

        </form>
```

**pdf.php**

```
    $studentName  = "";
    $studentDOB  = "";
    $parentName = "";
    $motherName = "";
    $email = "";
    $contact = "";
    $address = "";
    $city = "";
    $pincode = "";
    $Almnus="";
    $formType = "";

if($_REQUEST["formType"] == "LKG") {
    $studentName  = $_REQUEST["LKGStudentName"];
    $studentDOB  = $_REQUEST["LKGStudentDOB"];
    $parentName = $_REQUEST["LKGParentName"];
    $motherName = $_REQUEST["LKGMotherName"];
    $email = $_REQUEST["LKGEmail"];
    $contact = $_REQUEST["LKGContactNumber"];
    $address = $_REQUEST["LKGAddress"];
    $city = $_REQUEST["LKGCity"];
    $pincode = $_REQUEST["LKGPincode"];
    $Almnus= $_REQUEST["LKGAlmnus"];

    $formType = " LKG";
}






      $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $hostname = "localhost"; 
        $db = "abc";

        //connection to the database

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
        mysql_select_db($db,$dbhandle) or die('cannot select db');
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO admissions (studentname, parentname, emailaddress, phone, type, dob, mothername, address, city, pincode, almnus) 
    VALUES('$studentName', '$parentName', '$email', '$contact', '$formType', '$studentDOB', '$motherName', '$address', '$city', '$pincode', '$Almnus') ") or die(mysql_error());  

        // add a page
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $html = '
                    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
                    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
                    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
                    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
                    <h1>&nbsp;</h1>

    $html .= $formType;

    $html .= '</h3>
    <table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="50">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"  bgcolor="#f1f1f1" color="#000" align="left" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;border-top: 1px solid #ccc;"><h4>Online Admission Form Details</h4></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="30%" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">Student Name</td>
    <td width="70%" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">';

        $html .= $studentName;
        $html .= '</td>
                                       </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="30%" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">Student Date of Birth</td>
    <td width="70%" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">';

        $html .= $studentDOB;
        $html .= '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">Parent Name</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">    
    $html .= $parentName;
    $html .= '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">Mother Name</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">';
        $html .= $motherName;
        $html .= '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">Email Address</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">';
        $html .= $email;
        $html .= '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">Contact Number</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">';
        $html .= $contact;
        $html .= '</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">Residential Address</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">';

    style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">';
            $html .= $address;
            $html .= '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">City</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">';
            $html .= $city;
            $html .= '</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">Pin Code</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">';
            $html .= $pincode;
            $html .= '</td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">Almnus</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">';
            $html .= $Almnus;
            $html .= '</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
```

Comment: Did you search? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+checkboxes

Comment: ya.. But i m not getting whats wrong with my code..

Comment: Maybe is it is better to use radio buttons in this situation? Either you use one checkbox to indicate yes/no or you use Radio Buttons for two options.

Comment: 1) change to radio, 2) use the NAME in the PHP to get the value 3) use unique ID but same name for radio

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems none of the answerers can get the total fix in one answer, I guess I have to.

Problems:

1. The PHP is using ID instead of the NAME to access the request
2. You use TWO checkboxes instead of the more logical ONE checkbox OR two RADIOs
3. IDs need to be unique

Here is the PHP you need

```
$Almnus= $_REQUEST["LKGAlumnus"]; // watch the spelling, Get the NAME
```

Here is the solution with one checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="LKGAlumnus" value="Yes" id="LKGAlumnusYes" />
<label for="LKGAlumnusYes">Alumnus?</label>
```

Here is the solution with two radios

```
Alumnus?<input type="radio" name="LKGAlumnus" value="Yes" id="LKGAlumnusYes"/>
<label for="LKGAlumnusYes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="LKGAlumnus" value="No" id="LKGAlumnusNo" />
<label for="LKGAlumnusNo">No</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo causing a mismatch of names: `LKGAlumnus` and then `LKGAlmnus`. The first has two u's and the second has only one.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="LKGAlumnus" value="Yes" id="LKGAlmnus" >Yes &nbsp&nbsp
        <input type="checkbox" name="LKGAlumnus" value="No" id="LKGAlmnus" >No &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp

//...
$Almnus= $_REQUEST["LKGAlmnus"];
```

Comment: The name is sent to the server so it is the name he needs to match! Also make it a radio and it will work better

Answer (score 0):

You should use radio buttons instead of check-boxes if you want to get either of the option:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" name="LKGAlumnus" value="Yes" id="LKGAlmnusYes" >Yes</input>
<input type="radio" name="LKGAlumnus" value="No" id="LKGAlmnusNo" >No </input>
```

**PHP:**

```
$Almnus= $_POST["LKGAlumnus"];
```

Comment: This is basically a rundown of comments and you did not make the ID unique so you did not read all of them proper

Comment: Fixed the ID for you.